# Can I install wordpress twice on a domain

Tags: wordpress

I have a website mywebsite.com, I already have wordpress blog installed on mywebsite.com/blog; now I have a human french translated version of my website here fr.mywebsite.com, now I'm stuck between two choices:
1. Installing wordpress again on fr.website.com/blog and hire a french blog writer to take charge.
2. OR, Continue with the already existing mywebsite.com/blog and then get a machine translator to automatically switch between languages.

I want to know if it is Ok to have wordpress installed twice on my domain (1 on the main domain and 1 on the subdomain).

I really need the public's opinion to help me decide because I really want to search/google about this, but I didn't even know what to search for in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's OK. You can have multiple WordPress installs on your server so one on the main site and another on a subdomain. There's also [WordPress Multisite](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/), although the setup is a bit more complex than your regular WP site.

Answer (score 1):

A human translation maybe is better and you can have Taylor made content for each language. There is no problem having a second installation to the same domain.

You can also check for a multi site solution or even simpler using a multi language plugin.

Finally there is always the custom multilingual solution but it depends on your coding experience.

Of course this is my point of view